# Keeping focus on controlled TextField through updates to state, but also forcing update?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a controlled Material-UI TextField component that gets its value from the parent component's state. I'm not able to get the value to update without the TextField losing focus. Any help would be appreciated

```js
export function OtherApp() {

    const [stateArray, setStateArray] = useState([{name: 'first', value: 'val'}, {name: 'second', value: 'val'}])

    const changeHandler = (e, i) => {
        let state = stateArray;
        state[i].name = e.target.value;
        setStateArray(state);
        console.dir(state);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {stateArray.map((el, i) => {
                return (
                    <TextField
                        fullWidth
                        id={`section-${i}-namet`}
                        key={`section-${i}-namet`}
                        value={stateArray[i].name}
                        helperText='Helper Text'
                        onChange={e => changeHandler(e, i)}
                    />
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its always a best practice to clone the state before updating. Try adding below code in your changeHandler function

```
const changeHandler = (e, i) => {
  let state = [...stateArray];
  ...
}
```